# How can I create an RFC 3339 timestamp in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I inherited a TCL script (I have zero familiarity with the language) and need to add an RFC 3339 timestamp to it:

```
2012-04-05T12:13:32.123456-08:00
```

After searching Google, I haven't found any means of displaying the microseconds or the timezone offset (I have found a way to show the timezone name, but that doesn't help).
Is there a way to do this without calling an external process?

Comment: I believe this is going to be dependent on your version of TCL

Comment: @resmon6 The only problematic part will be getting the milliseconds; that wasn't available at all before 8.4, and the syntax changed in 8.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TCL8.5, you can try the following command:

```
% clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%dT%T%z"
2012-04-05T16:06:07-0500
```

That gives you everything except the sub-second resolution.  The `clock microseconds` command will give you the time in microseconds, but I can't find a format string identifier that matches it.  You can use this to build your own command from scratch:

```
proc timestamp_rfc3339 {} {
    set us [clock microseconds]
    set sec [expr {$us / 1000000}]
    set micro [expr {$us % 1000000}]
    set ts [clock format $sec -format "%Y-%m-%dT%T"]
    regexp {(...)(..)} [clock format $sec -format "%z"] matched tzh tzm
    return [format "%s.%06s%s:%s" $ts $micro $tzh $tzm]
}
```

Running this results in a timestamp like `2012-04-05T16:35:06.366378-05:00`.

**Edit:** Updated code sample to incorporate user1179884's tweaks (see comments) and to wrap in a proc.

Comment: I did this: `
    regexp {(...)(..)} [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%z"] matched hours minutes
    return [format "%s.%s%s:%s" [timestamp -format "%Y-%m-%dT%X"] [expr [clock microseconds] % 1000000] $hours $minutes]100000] $hours $minutes]`. Basically the same, but I used a regex to put a colon in the timezone offset, which is required in rfc3339.

Comment: One other thing necessary...I had to change the "%s" for the microseconds to "%06s" to keep the leading zeroes.

Comment: @user1179884: You should write down exactly what you did as a self-answer. (That's allowed!) Then we can show how to do the _exact_ solution to the problem, and vote it up too.

Comment: @user1179884- For completeness' sake, I'll edit my answer and incorporate your tweaks.